# Why does the compiler choose overload with IEnumerable over IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following two extension methods:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this IEnumerable self, object obj)
    {
        foreach (object o in self)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(o, obj))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool ContainsEither<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, T arg1, T arg2)
    {
        return self.Contains(arg1) || self.Contains(arg2);
    }
}
```

When I wrote my second method, I intended it to call the generic LINQ `Enumerable.Contains<T>` method (type arguments inferred from the usage). However, I found out that it is actually calling the first method (my custom `Contains()` extension method. When I comment out my `Contains()` method, the second method compiles fine, using the `Enumerable.Contains<T>()` method.

My question is, why does the compiler choose my `Contains()` method with non-generic `IEnumerable` argument over `Enumerable.Contains<T>()` with `IEnumerable<T>` argument? I would expect it to choose `Enumerable.Contains<T>()` because `IEnumerable<T>` is more derived than `IEnumerable`.

Comment: generics are more specific.

Comment: In general, in situations like this, the question "why" is generally interesting, but probably more important is the question "how do I make it not .....".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Really just about the why. I could have written Enumerable.Contains(...) or Contains<T>(...)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> My question is, why does the compiler choose my Contains() method with non-generic `IEnumerable` argument over `Enumerable.Contains<T>()` with `IEnumerable<T>` argument?

Because it's found in the same namespace that contains the method calling it. Types declared within that namespace effectively have precedence over types declared in imported namespaces.

From the C# 5 specification, section 7.6.5.2:

> The search for C proceeds as follows:
>
> - Starting with the closest enclosing namespace declaration, continuing with each enclosing namespace declaration, and ending with the containing compilation unit, successive attempts are made to find a candidate set of extension methods:
>
>   - If the given namespace or compilation unit directly contains non-generic type declarations Ci with eligible extension methods Mj, then the set of those extension methods is the candidate set.
>   - If namespaces imported by using namespace directives in the given namespace or compilation unit directly contain non-generic type declarations Ci with eligible extension methods Mj, then the set of those extension methods is the candidate set.
> - If no candidate set is found in any enclosing namespace declaration or compilation unit, a compile-time error occurs.